# Project to a "wireless" display over Ethernet?

Tags: windows-10, display

I have a Roku TV that supports Windows 10's "Wireless Display" feature. On my laptop, I am able to "Project" to it with no problem. (OK, it's actually pretty slow, but the point is that it works.) On my Windows 10 desktop, however, I can't connect to it or even get to the same menu.

For review, here's how to connect to a wireless display in Windows 10:

1. Open the Action Center (bottom right corner of the Windows 10 desktop)
2. Click on "Project" (If you don't see this option, you may first have to expand to view all the options, depending on your screen size)
3. Click on "Connect to a wireless display"
4. Select your desired wireless display
5. Profit

It's step #3 where things fall down. There is no "Connect to a wireless display" option on my desktop. My guess here is that since my desktop is connected to the network via Ethernet, Windows 10 somehow assumes that I won't be able to connect to a wireless display.

Apparently I'm not the only one running into this. [The same question was asked on the Windows forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/cast-to-device-over-ethernet/3cb8ee9c-b634-445b-b8de-5be1eeb2583c), but there haven't been any replies yet. There are dozens of us! Dozens!

Is this just a Windows 10 bug or does this "wireless display" feature use WiFi *specifically* to connect to the device, rather than connecting to a display on the network. If the answer is the latter, I'm interested to know how it does that because it's not something I'm familiar with.

Comment: If the desktop is using wired and the TV uses wireless, how do you expect them to connect? You will need to disable the wired adapter and enable the wireless one for it to work. But first run in Command Prompt (cmd) the command `netsh wlan show driver`. The last line should say "Wireless Display Supported : Yes".

Comment: @harrymc Sounds like you're trying to answer my last question: "does this 'wireless display' feature use WiFi specifically..." That command returns "There is no wireless interface on the system." My assumption is that the "wireless display" feature connects devices over the same LAN, in which case I don't see why a wireless connection is required at all. Does this "wireless display" feature actually do some kind of point-to-point wireless communication?

Comment: Computer and TV should both be connected to the network. Computer can be via wired and TV by wireless. Projecting should then find the TV.

Comment: @harrymc Agreed! That's what I expected also. Both the computer and the TV are on the same network. The problem is not that the device isn't showing up, it's that my desktop doesn't even let me _list_ display devices on the network. The "Connect to a wireless display" option is absent from the menu where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Are you trying to stream media from your PC to your TV, or do you actually want to cast your Windows desktop to the Roku?

Comment: @jrichall The use case is desktop casting. I'm hosting a hackathon in a few days, and I'd like to have a way for people to share their screens to the TV to share things. I have a Chromecast, but the performance is really poor compared to laptop->TV casting. Sounds like from harrymc's answer that the Windows 10 "wireless display" feature really is based on WiFi somehow, so only people connected to WiFi will be able to use it. Either the Chromecast or my long HDMI cable will work as backups. That, or I set up a dedicated laptop and have a video call running all day. IDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your computer's hardware doesn't support
[WiDi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiDi) then you can't cast.
You will need to get a device that can, for example Chromecast
(sender & receiver).

You can still stream video files over the network by using a media server like
[Serviio](http://serviio.org/)
if your TV is smart enough to find your computer,
but you can't mirror without Miracast/WiDi.

Answer (score 14):

This topic is a little old, but I'll put this here for future questions and for people that are still curious.

Windows 10 version 1703 extended the Miracast to Miracast over Infrastructure (Ethernet).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure

So both Wireless as well as Ethernet is now supported

EDIT:
The actual idea of projecting over Ethernet using Windows 10 default support is now definitely supported as seen in the above link Miracast over Infrastructure (MICE).

MS-MICE is a recent feature added into Windows 10 version 1703 to support Miracast over Ethernet. I've not seen the technology being implemented yet however, based on the specs and descriptions it does sound promising.

Regarding your question, I'm assuming this would work on newer Windows 10 against the Miracast Wi-Fi Roku device but I don't have a Roku device to test. However, in the specs, they mentioned that the source and sink could either be Ethernet or Wi-Fi, so I'm assuming it's interchangeable. (I'm assuming you're thinking of having Ethernet Windows 10 and a WiFi Roku)

```
As a Miracast receiver, the Surface Hub or device must be connected to your enterprise network via either Ethernet or a secure Wi-Fi connection (e.g. using either WPA2-PSK or WPA2-Enterprise security). If the Surface Hub or device is connected to an open Wi-Fi connection, Miracast over Infrastructure will disable itself.
As a Miracast source, the Windows PC or phone must be connected to the same enterprise network via Ethernet or a secure Wi-Fi connection.
```

[Reference from MS-MICE Specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-mice/ab6341b7-4fc7-41fd-a74d-3fe023455482)

[Enabling MS-MICE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure)

I've not tested this feature yet, but I'm following development of [Lazycast](https://github.com/homeworkc/lazycast), Lazycast is a casting system that is compatible with Windows 10 Miracast on RPi and other Linux systems, I've tested this on my RPi4 and my Ubuntu Tablet and it works seamlessly as I connected to them as a Wireless Display, even the keyboard and mouse input works.

Lazycast lately has been developing on the MICE support, so if you're interested in trying out MICE, Lazycast could be one source.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer helped a lot. There's one important thing from the Microsoft docs that you omitted: the device must have a Wi-Fi interface enabled in order to respond to discovery requests that only occur through the Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: See also the FAQ on that link: "Why do I still need Wi-Fi to use Miracast over infrastructure?
Discovery requests to identify Miracast receivers can only occur through the Wi-Fi adapter. Once the receivers have been identified, Windows 10 can then attempt the connection to the network."

Answer (score 0):

**The technology is actually designed to do it through wireless**. Somehow, if your TV is connected to Internet with Ethernet cable, you should be able to mirror your screen with a 2.4ghz wireless connected computer. In most scenarios, I dont know why but 5ghz wireless connections doesn't reach to your TV via Ethernet cable.

If you want to cast your screen to your TV using Ethernet, make sure the computer connected to 2.4 ghz network wireless and also Ethernet plugged. That way, your TV (at least Samsung Smart TVs) will be able to catch the connection.

PS: Answer is based on my personal experience, it might not work on a different model TV or with a different router.